# CSS Input Slider Range Customize crossbrowser

Tags: jquery, css

I have a slider design which is based on IE's.

I cannot find anything similar on the net which works cross browser.

Can this be done at all, cross browser?

Comment: might help https://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is a lot out there. Here are a couple of examples. Not only cross-browser but also responsive and configurable.

Ion RangeSlider http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html

Let me know if you find what you are looking for.